# Is it possible to do a lookup on a view in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to build a new mongodb view using an aggregation with a $lookup stage that joins to a mongodb view I built.

Here is a sample of the resulting output from my view named myPreferencesView:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c3127b30abaf0d1ae38235"), 
    "name" : "Preference 1", 
    "pointValue" : NumberInt(12), 
    "description" : "This is the desc for preference #1"
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c3127b30abaf0d1ae38234"), 
    "name" : "Preference 2", 
    "pointValue" : NumberInt(10), 
    "description" : "This is the desc for preference #2"
}
```

Here is the $lookup syntax I tried:

```
$lookup:
{
    from: "myPreferencesView (on: myPreferenceCollection)",
    localField: "preference",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "pref"
}
```

I am getting results that look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58c3127b30abaf0d1ae3822f"), 
    "preference" : ObjectId("58c3127b30abaf0d1ae38232"), 
    "pref" : [
    ]
}
```

I am getting an empty pref array. I am wondering first of all, can an aggregation or view do a $lookup on a mongodb view.

Secondly, is there special syntax needed to do so?

I have tried a few different tweaks to the lookup syntax listed above. Most of those attempts were clearly wrong because they didn't produce workable results. The syntax above seems to "not break" but it also doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: You can do it. but that will result to poor performance

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#views-and-collation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the syntax posted in the original question was fine, and it does work. The issue I was having is that the "sub view" name I had specified in the $lookup stage had a casing issue.

Comment: can you please post your solution.

Comment: @rakesh please see my syntax in the original question. That syntax works.